# Click on custom button in android

Tags: android, android-button

I have created a custom button for my application.

```
class CustomButton(context: Context) : AppCompatButton(context) {

private var lastClickTime: Long = 0

override fun setOnClickListener(l: OnClickListener?) {
    if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastClickTime < 1000){
        return
    }
    lastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();
    super.setOnClickListener(l)
}
```

}

I am trying to use this for blocking double clicks
but the `setonClickListener` only calls once. on the second time, the parent clicks not invoke.

Comment: `setOnClickListener()` should only run once (usually). It's the `onClick(view: View)` function in the `OnClickListener` interface that runs each time you click. You might be able to accomplish what you want by overriding `performClick()` instead, but I haven't really thought that all the way through, atm.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own listener for double click. Something like this

```
abstract class MyListener : View.OnClickListener {
    private var lastClickTime: Long = 0

    override fun onClick(view: View?) {
        if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - lastClickTime >= 1000) {
            onDoubleClick(view)
        }
        lastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime()
    }

    abstract fun onDoubleClick(view: View?)
}
```

and use it

```
myButton.setOnClickListener(object : MyListener() {
    override fun onDoubleClick(view: View?) {
                    
    }
})
```